# Java regex with reserved chars

Tags: java, android, regex, replace

I'm using a pattern string like this

```
url = "http://myWebsite.com:1700/[LANG]/service/?customerid=[CUSTOMERID]";
```

I'm using this code to replace parameters.

```
url.replace("[LANG]", languageName);
```

also tryied :

```
url.replace("\\[LANG\\]", languageName);
```

but not worked.

Comment: You mean you tried `url = url.replace("[LANG]", languageName);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java Strings are immutable. `replace()` returns a new string and you need to capture it:

```
url = url.replace("[LANG]", languageName);
```

Comment: If it is an answer, the question is a duplicate.

Comment: @stribizhev Sure. For simple answers like this it takes less time to write an answer than to search for a canonical duplicate.

Comment: @stribizhev ...and I bet that duplicate is also duplicate.

Comment: I found one very quickly. But I wanted to hear from OP first whether the assignment to the variable actually took place.

Comment: @stribizhev In that case feel free to use your hammer early. If OP will update his question with more details you can propose new duplicate another mjolnir owner can reopen this question and use new duplicate.

Comment: @Pshemo: I just have a strong trust in people :) that is my Kryptonite.